# MySQL UNION ALL with LEFT JOIN returning double values

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have multiple tables trying to get values from all tables using UNION ALL and LEFT JOIN in MySql the query I used look like bellow.

```
(SELECT 
   t1.name, t2.cat, t3.utt, t4.gcost, t4.net
 FROM table_one as t1
   LEFT JOIN table_three as t2
     ON t2.id = t1.ct
   LEFT JOIN table_four as t3
     ON t3.id = t1.ut
   LEFT JOIN table_five as t4
     ON t4.gid = t1.id
 ) UNION ALL
 (SELECT 
   t1.name, t2.cat, t3.utt, t4.gcost, t4.net
 FROM table_tow as t1
   LEFT JOIN table_three as t2
     ON t2.id = t1.ct
   LEFT JOIN table_four as t3
     ON t3.id = t1.ut
   LEFT JOIN table_five as t4
     ON t4.gid = t1.id
 )
```

but the above query return double values in MySQL

here is fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd30ba/1

any help would be appreciated.

thanks

**UPDATE**

as per  P.Salmon  question to know the complete logic the above query is using for Fixed assets App, so fixed assets has multiple item values like:

1. actual price.
2. Accumulated Depreciation
3. Current Value
4. ...

so the query in fiddle there are 2 different price/amount the query should return both values for each reference row id.

Comment: what is the output you are expecting?

Comment: if you check fiddle there are only 8 entries it should return only 8 but query returning 16.

Comment: 16 rows are because in `table_five` column `gid` value is repeated twice so you are getting double entries.

Comment: I know that's repeated because there is tow tables, table_one and table_tow... and gid belongs these tow tables row id.

Comment: 16 is correct given your code for example big banana has 2 prices(gcost). If you only want 1 big banana please state which one and the  filter rule(s).

Comment: If I use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` it removes all duplicate rows between the two SELECT statements. I'm left with 14 rows. I do find your table names and alias names confusing.

Comment: @P.Salmon there is only 1 big banana with 2 prices but query returning 2 big banana with 2 different prices, it means query is returning wrong values.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware your right removing ALL return 14 records. but still it's wrong returning.

Comment: @ash how can 1 big banana have 2 prices? If it can then choose only one price because 2 different prices result in 2 different rows

Comment: 'it means query is returning wrong values' - no, one big banana 2 prices means 2 rows should be returned in the absence of any filter..or other selection criteria - if you want only 1 row you need to explain the logic..

Comment: @aRvi that's because one is the actual price and second is Depreciation value so in fiddle I just add a random number, for both of values.

Comment: @ash in that case you should use group by and pick the actual value or the Depreciation value. Then only 8 rows will be returned.

Comment: @P.Salmon I have update my question.

Comment: '2 different price/amount the query should return both values for each reference row id.' - appears to contradict(lost in translation?) what you have said so far. It would help if you added your desired outcome as text to the question big banana would be could all would be better.

Comment: @P.Salmon I changed Big Banana to Grapes.:)

Comment: Then you will get 2 rows for grapes- in a 1 to n join you will always get n returned in the absence of any filters.

Comment: @P.Salmon I know but is there a way to get only 1 row instead of 2 rows ? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone for helping but none of these helped me, I know there are repeated ID's in table_five, from table_one and table_tow... the only way I solve my problem I add new sequence ID in table_one, table_tow ... AS

```
seq_.time();
```

same sequence adding in table_five during insert.. after that I changed the query to.

```
(SELECT 
   t1.name, t2.cat, t3.utt, t4.gcost, t4.net
 FROM table_one as t1
   LEFT JOIN table_three as t2
     ON t2.id = t1.ct
   LEFT JOIN table_four as t3
     ON t3.id = t1.ut
   LEFT JOIN table_five as t4
     ON t4.gid = t1.id
     AND t4.seq = t1.seq
 ) UNION ALL
 (SELECT 
   t1.name, t2.cat, t3.utt, t4.gcost, t4.net
 FROM table_tow as t1
   LEFT JOIN table_three as t2
     ON t2.id = t1.ct
   LEFT JOIN table_four as t3
     ON t3.id = t1.ut
   LEFT JOIN table_five as t4
     ON t4.gid = t1.id
    AND t4.seq = t1.seq
 )
```

now I get exact data as I want.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You only want one and REALLY don't care which one then max the t5 details

```
select t1.name,t3.cat,t4.utt, 
         t5.gcost,t5.net
 from
 (
 select * from table_one
 union all
 select * from table_two) t1
 LEFT JOIN table_three as t3 ON t3.id = t1.ct
 LEFT JOIN table_four as t4            ON t4.id = t1.ct
 left join (select gid,max(gcost) gcost,max(net) net from table_five group by gid) t5 on t5.gid = t1.id;
+--------------+------+------+-------+------+
| name         | cat  | utt  | gcost | net  |
+--------------+------+------+-------+------+
| Green Apple  | A    | AAA  |  3000 | 6542 |
| Small Orange | B    | BBB  |  2560 | 6542 |
| Small Banana | C    | CCC  |  5800 | 6542 |
| Small Mango  | C    | DDD  |  2560 | 6542 |
| Red Apple    | A    | AAA  |  3000 | 6542 |
| Big Orange   | B    | BBB  |  2560 | 6542 |
| Big Banana   | C    | CCC  |  5800 | 6542 |
| Big Mango    | C    | DDD  |  2560 | 6542 |
+--------------+------+------+-------+------+
8 rows in set (0.072 sec)
```

Comment: thank you but this is not what I want, your query grouping ID's and getting the first value.. if you check fiddle Green Apple and Red apple have same price/values..